# Can't see online meeting created using GraphAPI in Outlook Calendar

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have created an online meeting using GraphAPI by using token acquired by following the steps in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service). But those meetings are not displayed in Outlook calendar. Is there any way to view it in calendar?

Comment: What request did you send to the graph to create the event? The documentation you're pointing to is only about app registrations and tokens

Comment: @baywet I used this [request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-beta)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Online meetings are only the representation of a conferencing space (to video call, phone in, chat...) They do not send any information or block anything on the calendar.
You need to [create an exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0) event as well to have an invite sent to the attendees and add the online meeting information to that event if you want them to be able to join the conference.